# NZEC error in Python - SPOJ

Tags: python-2.7

```
def multiply(num1, num2):
    result = num1 * num2
    print(result)
    return result

tc = raw_input("") #testcases
tc = [int(tc)]
#count = [int(count)]
count = 0
while ( count < tc) :
    var1, var2 = raw_input("").split()
    var1, var2 = [int(var1), int(var2)]
    multiply (var1,var2)
    print '\n'`**enter code here**`
    count = count + 1
```

I'm getting NZEC on SPOJ . I'm new to python programming . 
Please help me. Thanks in advance . [Link to the Question on SPOJ](http://www.spoj.com/problems/MUL/%60)

Comment: The link in the question doesn't work due to additional "/%60" string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in you code:

**Line 7**: `tc = [int(tc)]`

You shouldn't wrap variable `tv` into the list. You have created a singleton with the number of test cases as an element. Variable `tc` should be a number, therefore, the line should look like this:

`tc = int(tc)`

**Line 14**: print '\n'`**enter code here**`

You should remove the weird part "`**enter code here**`".

After mentioned changes your code should be a correct solution to the [MUL](http://www.spoj.com/problems/MUL/) problem on Spoj.